# Usage of since as a preposition

Tags: british-english

I've felt better since I have been there.

Why (perfect tense) is written in this sentence after since? 
Shouldn't we use simple past there ?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is puzzling. One would expect to read:

> > I've felt better since I have been *here*

because the (present perfect) *have been* means from a point in the past up to the present moment, and where-ever you are at present is *here*, not *there*.

So, logically, if not grammatically, you need to write either:

> > I've felt better since I have been (or since *being*) here

or

> > I've felt better since I was there

Comment: Shorter, and probably more likely in the real world: ***I feel better since going there***.

Comment: It has been written in Oxford dictionary , might be that dictionary has mistakenly printed this .

Answer (score 0):

In the right context, this could be grammatically correct and natural:

> "I'm happy with the place. I've felt better since I have
>   been there."

In this case, the speaker:

-is not physically at the place while speaking

-continues to inhabit the place

-at some time in the past was not inhabiting the place

-has felt better since inhabiting the place